# Enable compression on linux hosting

Tags: jquery, linux, .htaccess, compression, hosting

I configure my `.htaccess` file in this way:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

But, `https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/` said me that i can save more space enabling the compression for this: `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js`

Have i missed some parameters?

Comment: but do you see that headers are being set, that server has gziped your file `jquery....min.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including jquery from the http://code.jquery.org URL? Then there is not much you can do. It's the server administrator of that server that will need to setup compression.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Can i solve it saving (in locale) the jquery-1.11.3.min.js file?

Comment: Yes! But be aware that then you miss out on the advantage you get from users already having this file in their local browser cache because they may have visited other sites that included this file.

Comment: Ok, i haven't considered this. Thank you.